# ReactJS Router is overriding ExpressJS router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have encountered very interesting problem. My React JS root file has multiple routers:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container body">
                <Route exact path="/" component={<IndexPage/>} />
                <Route exact path="/users" component={<Users/>} />
                <Route exact path="/users/:userId" component={<User/> }/>
                <Route exact path="/routers" component={<Routers/>} />
        </div> 
    );
}
```

I generate Component depending on route. Then I have build my react components as single javascript file by webpack.

Now I'm trying to show React pages via ExpressJS like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// This is location where generated Webpack files are located
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../build'));

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.json({hello: 'world'})
});

// This is how I render React based pages
app.get(['/', '/users', '/routers'], (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../build/index.html');
});

app.listen(9000);
```

When I open `/`, `/users`, `/routers` paths by my browser, it shows correct React Components.

However, when I try to open `/api/hello`, It is still trying to generate React Component that does not exist, instead of showing JSON response!

How to stop making React's router overriding Express' router?

**=================UPDATE=====================**

I have found interesting solution. When I made `api/hello` request via **POSTMAN** it has shown to me JSON response.

That means that ReactJS has its own CACHING in browser level which makes it seem like overriding routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found interesting solution. When I made api/hello request via POSTMAN it has shown to me JSON response.

That means that ReactJS has its own CACHING in browser level which makes it seem like overriding routes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was scratching my head whole day.